# How can I connect to a wireless network using only the command line in Linux?

Tags: linux, wireless-networking

How can I connect to a wireless network using only the command line in Linux?  The only thing I know is that `iwconfig` must be used, but how?

Answer (score 6):

The exact commands will depend on the network you're connecting to.
I generally first use 'iwlist' to find a list of available networks.

```
iwlist wlan0 scanning
```

This will return a list of all wireless networks seen on interface wlan0.

The next step is to set the ESSID and what access point to use (usually automatic).

```
iwconfig wlan0 essid my_network
iwconfig wlan0 ap any
```

If the network is unsecured you're done configuring the wifi at this point. You can then set a static IP (ifconfig) or a request a dynamic IP (dhclient).

If the network is secured with WEP you'll need to enter the correct key.

```
iwconfig wlan0 enc s:my_network_key
```

If the network is secured with WPA(2) you'll need to install and configure wpa_supplicant first.

As always the manpage is the first place you should look for more information.

Comment: Not all wireless networks are seen on wlan0. I've got an Acer laptop where the wireless network is on eth1. I'd add a step to first check the correct interface using `iwconfig`

Comment: How do you know what to use as access point?